# Why does Uosuke say "Tai" at the end of every sentence?

Tags: fairy-tail

In Fairy Tail 2014, Uosuke is a member of the Garou Knights, the most powerful executioners of Fiore (per the Fairy Tail Wikia). Apart from the fact that he loves fish or has a strange obsession with fish, is there any other particular reason why he says "Tai" at the end of every sentence.

I have a feeling that tai could be inferring/referring to fish tails (per his obssession/love for fish). Are there any other reasons as to why he adds "Tai" at the end of every sentence? If not, is it just for entertainment purposes? E.g. to be funny?

Comment: What do you think about Cancer?? Why he says -ebi? xD

Comment: @berserk- Hahahaha. Yeah, true that. xDDD

Answer (score 2):

Tai is the japanese name for the sea bream, a fish known for its taste. A lot of anime characters add suffixes to their sentences, to give the character a little uniqueness, like Naruto's -ttebayo. So, since Uosuke really likes fish, he suffixes -tai to his sentences.